# How to express a percentage?

Tags: word-usage, prepositional-phrases, numbers

I have to put the decimal number 10% in a sentence as a statement of comparison.

Can I say:

10% out of all number of caves. (?)

Answer (score 3):

> **10% of all caves**

is the correct way to phrase it.
**Out of** is understood since you've already mentioned the population of **all caves**